# Canvas gets width and height after resize + bug on update

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have recently started with canvas. I would like to move elements on mousemove in canvas. It wasn't a problem but then I added a resize function to make it fluid. After that the width and height of canvas is set just after the resizing even when I set width and height(so you have to resize the window to get a width and height for canvas or it has no width and height) and also the "eyes" are leaving the track after themself so the canvas is not clearing or updating(?) but I cannot find out why. any help would be appreciated.

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/62jkx9rj/2/

JS :

```
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
    })();

    var ctx,
      widthCanvas,
      heightCanvas,
      leftEye,
      rightEye,
      mouse;

    Eye = function(pos) {
      this.pos = {
        x: pos.x,
        y: pos.y
      };
      this.center = {
        x: pos.x,
        y: pos.y
      };
      this.translation = {
        x: (window.innerWidth / 2 - canvas.width / 2) + this.center.x,
        y: this.center.y
      };
    }

    Eye.prototype.draw = function() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, 7, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y - 4, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
      ctx.fill();
    }

    Eye.prototype.update = function() {
      var deltaX = mouse.x - this.translation.x;
      var deltaY = mouse.y - this.translation.y;
      var mag = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
      var angleRad = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
      var newPosX = this.center.x + 6 * Math.cos(angleRad);
      var newPosY = this.center.y + 6 * Math.sin(angleRad);
      this.pos.x += (newPosX - this.pos.x) / 5;
      this.pos.y += (newPosY - this.pos.y) / 5;
    }

    var init = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var $canvas = $('#canvas');
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      container = $("body");
      widthCanvas = 300;
      heightCanvas = 250;

      $(window).resize(resizeCanvas);
      function resizeCanvas() {
        widthCanvas = $canvas.attr('width', $(container).width());
        heightCanvas = $canvas.attr('height', $(container).height());

      }
      resizeCanvas();
      canvas.width = widthCanvas;
      canvas.height = heightCanvas;
      leftEye = new Eye({
        x: 130,
        y: 95
      });
      rightEye = new Eye({
        x: 160,
        y: 85
      });
      mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      };
      bindEventHandlers();
      draw();
    }

    var draw = function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, widthCanvas, heightCanvas);
      leftEye.update();
      rightEye.update();
      leftEye.draw();
      rightEye.draw();
      requestAnimFrame(draw);
    }

    var bindEventHandlers = function() {
      document.onmousemove = function(e) {
        mouse.x = e.pageX;
        mouse.y = e.pageY;
      }
    }

    init();
```

Comment: can you write a few sentences about the expected behaviour? I don't see anything but a red dot

Comment: try to resize the jsfiddle result window and you will see the canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working version: https://jsfiddle.net/62jkx9rj/6/

I have the 1st problem fixed: You have both $canvas, canvas. I removed $canvas:

```
function resizeCanvas() {
  widthCanvas = canvas.width = $(container).width();
  heightCanvas = canvas.height = $(container).height();
}
```

And here's the fix to the 2nd problem. Also because of the confusion of $canvas, canvas. Change the 1st line of draw:

```
var draw = function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Gavriel. This is absolutely right